# How do I update the postgresql database after I've already imported all the data?

Tags: postgresql, osm2pgsql

I ran osm2pgsql and it worked great but then I spent a few days adding a whole other PBF only to find that I had forgotten the append flag and I can't render any of the new data.

Does anyone know what command I have to run to fix this without wasting all the CPU cycles and disk space of reimporting?

Comment: If you didn't --append, it replaced the data. Its gone. Perhaps restore from backup.

Comment: Isn't this the same as http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222801/not-rendering-new-data-after-second-import ? If not, can you explain the difference a little more clearly?

Comment: @BradHards Yes. I posted that other question after I understood the problem a little bit better. The problem isn't that the data was over written, it is that the data what should be there now isn't.

Comment: I think you should have clicked edit, rather than posted a new question. You can close whichever one is worse.